# Can odata-generator-maven-plugin somehow generate all classes Serializable?

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I want to generate with com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel:odata-generator-maven-plugin:4.20.0 a Java client and all the generated classes must implement the interface Serializeable.

How can I instruct the generator to do this?

BR,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

The POJOs generated by the [Cloud SDK's OData (both V2 and V4) generators](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/vdm-generator) **cannot** be configured/tweaked to implement the `Serializable` interface.

However, all generated POJOs are indeed serializable using either [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) out of the box.

Comment: I want to use this generated client in an applicationserver and therefore it is necessary that the objects can be de/serialized with the Java object serialization to persist the state in specific situations. Are there any plans to enable the generator for this or any other solutions?

Comment: As of now, there are no plans for enabling this. However, this is also the first time I hear about this requirement. I can bring this request to our product owner, but since we are working on our next major version release, chances are not too high that this is getting implemented, I fear.